# Can I input a variable into HTML and give it to CSS to update a gauge reading?

Tags: html, css, esp32

I am trying to write a bit of code to read a sensor and, with my ESP32 make a webpage that will display the value.

But on a gauge with a "needle" ( think speedometer type of thing ) like output, I can make variables in CSS and I can make the gauge in CSS and display in HTML fine.
I can change the value of the gauge by changing the CSS variable BUT I want to be able to pass this varibale to CSS from my HTML file.

This is so I can process the HTML page on my ESP32, updating the value of the sensor and display it, I can't seem to get an option of updating CSS varible through HTML.

I would like to rather stay away from JavaScript to be hoest, I'm already learning CSS and HTML to make this work, but if need be I will do it.

Or could I do this in PHP perhaps ?

Any advice ?

Comment: Where is this dynamic value coming from?  Client-side functionality or server-side functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make this dynamic, you have no other option rather than to recur to JavaScript in combination with what you are using. From what I understand it's something like either a percentage value or a rotation degree value you are toying around with.

What I can recommend for your specific case is to use an inline style to change the position of your indicator.

Something like:

```
<div style="width: 99%;"></div>
```

It would help if you share with us what you have as code till now.

Also, from what I understand you are still new to this sort of coding, but something that would probably work really well for you could be [Socket.io](https://socket.io/) you just assign a port that receives information and configure it, and you could configure your ESP32 to send info to that port I suppose, not really familiar with that part though.

Comment: Thank, looks like I am going to go down this route, to be honest I dont really know what questions to ask right now but this has at least given me a direction to go in. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want really real time value refreshing with esp32 on its own web you have to use websockets.
I don't know what server library you using, but there are a couple of websocket libaries out there.
I recommend [ESP32_AsyncWebserver from Me_no_Dev](https://github.com/me-no-dev/ESPAsyncWebServer). This is a fully async webserver implementation, and it is containing the async websocket too.

If you succesfully implemented that to your project, and loaded your static html file with the gauge you mentioned, on runtime of the esp32 you can send websocket text messages to the front-end javascript code. Once you received the messages on the javascript side you can easily update anything from there.

If you interested in this more, i will write some code for you in here. Just let me know.

Comment: I'm going to go for a javaScript based aproach I think, done some research into that and while its yet another thing to learn I think I will have better luck with it, all still new on this side of things.Thanks so much for the help though.

Comment: I suggest you some arduino esp32 libraries if you don't mind.

First of all the webserver. I really recommend the AsyncWebServer from me_no_dev
[Here is a link](https://github.com/me-no-dev/ESPAsyncWebServer)
It has a built in websocket handler. This is also asyncron.
Follow the guides carefully.

For the file system  i recommend the LITTLEFS library, not the build in SPIFFS.
 [Here is a link](https://github.com/lorol/LITTLEFS)